# Connect to AWS DocumentDB from within a docker container

Tags: docker, aws-documentdb

B"H

I have a docker container on EC2 attempting to connect to DocumentDB. DocuementDB needs to be within the vpc network.
When attempting to connect to DocumentDB in a none host mode the connection fails, but when I (hack and) mount the container to use host network mode it does work. But for simple deployments and replicating my containers it's a problem.

Any idea how to connect to DocumentDB (without ssh tunneling) from within docker hosted on EC2?

Comment: It's not so easy to help you without more info. But do you have at least the correct ports published on your docker container?

Comment: It seems like the http requests would need to be made on behalf of the EC2 machine, not the container, for VPC constraints. But it's not a scalable approach

Comment: I suppose the ec2-user has the IAM policies to allow for that, and whatever user you use inside the container does not. I played with this stuff, and found it a lot more practical to use ecs fargate. There you make sure the ecs_task_role has the right permissions and then you can do this. At least that is how I connect from a springboot service to RDS (mysql).

Comment: @Chai DocumentDB has unique permissions that do not make it accessible outside the it amazon VPC.

Comment: Yes, if you put the Db in a private subnet inside a vpc, then you have to connect from there. So your container could also be inside that same private subnet/vpc, and then it should be able to connect. You will have to have for instance a loadbalancer to connect to from outside and forward traffic to the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are running the container in none networking mode. None means you want to disable all the networking for your container.  Most frequent used modes are either bridge or host.

You can also refer the below post which talks how to run docker container in ECS and connect to documentdb.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/deploy-a-containerized-application-with-amazon-ecs-and-connect-to-amazon-documentdb-securely/